# I cannot enable ASP Classic on Windows 8.1

Tags: iis, vbscript, installation, asp-classic, iis-6

I am trying to enable ASP Classic on my local PC windows 8.1. I have followed the steps to enable ASP in this Windows KB > https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/iis/application-frameworks/running-classic-asp-applications-on-iis-7-and-iis-8/classic-asp-not-installed-by-default-on-iis#installing-classic-asp-on-windows-8-or-windows-81

However when I go to the simple ASP Classic page I have created in a folder under inetpub/wwwroot/test/test.asp which just tries to do a simple Response.Write("TEST") on the page when I go to file:///C:/inetpub/wwwroot/test/test.asp all I see is my ASP code in text on the page. I enabled ASP, ISAPI filters and anything else that seemed relevant but it doesn't seem to run.

Is there not a VBScript DLL that needs to be enabled somewhere that isn't present in the Application Development Features under World Wide Web Services as I thought both VBScript and the ASP DLLS were needed to run ASP Classic?

Anyway I followed the KB article and still all I see are the text of the ASP page when I go to the local URL.

I also have WAMPServer installed on my PC but I have that under a different port 8888 so that I can toggle between the two. I have no problems starting WAMP and running PHP code it is just the IIS I am having issues with.

If I just enable IIS and go to localhost I get the default IIS page e.g file:///C:/inetpub/wwwroot/iis-85.png but I cannot get the ASP code to actually execute, it just shows up as text on the page.

How can I get this to work? I never used to have problems switching between the two servers ASP and WAMP but after a factory reset on this laptop I am having issues.

Comment: You say when you go to `file:///C:/inetpub/wwwroot/test/test.asp`. If your address begins with "file:///C:/" then what you are doing is opening the file directly into the browser, you aren't using the server at all.  Try `http://localhost/test/test.asp` or `http://127.0.0.1/test/test.asp`.  NB, you can also run PHP on IIS, I've never bothered with WAMP

Comment: how do u run PHP on Windows without WAMP? What do you use. I did have it set up so it was on a different port so I could run IIS  on localhost and PHP on https://127.0.0.1:8888/somepage.php

Comment: I use IIS.  Here's how to configure it. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/application-frameworks/install-and-configure-php-applications-on-iis/using-fastcgi-to-host-php-applications-on-iis